# 3 arrays in Material UI Autocomplete

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

I'm making a search input with several suggestions for the user to choose by. I'm using the Material UI's autocomplete:

```
import React from 'react';
import './SearchBar.css'
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Autocomplete from '@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete';


export default class Searchbar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        searchWord: '',
        collectionOfOptions1: [{ 'name': 'Bob' }, { 'name': 'loby' }, { 'title': 'Ben' }],
        collectionOfOptions2: [{ 'name': 'Heba' }, { 'name': 'bobbby' }],
        collectionOfOptions3: [{ 'title': 'Hammers' }, { 'title': 'Briar on safari' }]
    };
  }

 render() {
    return (
        <Autocomplete
            id="combo-box-demo"
            options={this.state.options}
            getOptionLabel={option => option.title}
            style={{ width: 300 }}
            renderInput={params => <TextField {...params} label="Combo box" 
            variant="outlined" />}
            renderOption={option => (
                <React.Fragment>
                    <span>{option.title}</span>
                </React.Fragment>
            )}
        />
    );
 }
}
```

I want to show the collections linke on the image: [image]

Is it possible and how to do it in the Material UI Autocomplete?

Comment: Material UI `Grid` may fit your demand

Comment: But how do i render it?

Comment: Have you made a try on it? https://material-ui.com/components/grid/

Comment: In the Autocomplete there is a function called renderOption where I parse just one of the options how do I get all of the options in there and do you mean adding the Grid in the renderOption?

Comment: Grid is a responsive layout component, you can write your Autocomplete Inside the Grid

Comment: Then I think I haven't formulated the question right. I want to display the array's of options inside the autocomplete in renderOption and show the options like on the image.